# Assembly: ..relocation truncated to fit

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att

Using Linux x86 assembly and AT&T syntax I'd like to do a program that for *max* times, prints the counter of this loop. I've tried with this:

```
.data

.text

.global main

diff    =   48
max     =   5   

count:  .byte   0
p:      .byte   0

main:

compare:
    movb    $count,%al
    cmp     $max,%al
    jnb     end

    movl    $4,%eax
    movl    $1,%ebx
    xor     %ecx,%ecx
    addb    $diff,%cl
    addb    $count,%cl
    movb    %cl,p
    movb    $p,%cl
    movl    $1,%edx
    int     $0x80

    movb    $count,%al
    inc     %al
    movb    %al,count
    jmp     compare

end:
    movl    $1,%eax
    movl    $0,%ebx
    int     $0x80
```

But gcc gives me these errors:

```
/tmp/ccqobwxL.o: In function `compare':
(.text+0x3): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.text'
/tmp/ccqobwxL.o: In function `compare':
(.text+0x19): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.text'
/tmp/ccqobwxL.o: In function `compare':
(.text+0x21): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.text'
/tmp/ccqobwxL.o: In function `compare':
(.text+0x2a): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What are the problems and how can I fix them?

Comment: Things like this `addb $count,%cl` are trying to add the address of count to _CL_. You want to add what is at `count`, not the address. `addb    $diff,%cl` works because you ave defined `diff` as a constant. `count` is defined as a byte so `$count` is the address of that byte. The same issue with `$p`. In the case of `$count` and `$p` drop the `$` sign. Then they will be treated as memory operands and not constant (immediate) values.

Comment: What's the error with _p_?

Comment: `movb    $p,%cl` is adding `$p` (the address of p) to _CL_.

Comment: I've just corrected it, thanks.